# meteor onepage_scroll package not working with tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, webkit

Gist of code: https://gist.github.com/FA-ViPer/325251949e6dc70d0278

Issue on package: https://github.com/eahefnawy/meteor-onepage-scroll-0.9/issues/1

I use a template to create my div sections and have one jquery call that executes when it is rendered on a new page. From trouble shooting, it looks like when I go from one page to the next the classes will still update but the webkit-transform fails to be updated in the style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've moved to using the fullPage.js package (meteor add lawshe:fullpage). I ran into the same issue, but it can be overcome by running fullpage.destroy in template.destroyed.